# Facebook share success callback?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I would like to know if I can check if my content was actually shared in Facebook?

I'm using Facebook SDK 4.1.x and `FBSDKShareButton`

The user has to authorize my app in Facebook, so I have a FB access token.

And I have this method to test the Share button

```
func newShareButton(){
    let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com.br")
    content.contentTitle = "Test title"
    content.contentDescription = "Test description"
    content.imageURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com.br/images/nav_logo225.png")

    shareButton.shareContent = content

}
```

Everything is working fine, but I can't figure it out how to get the response, if the user actually shared the content.

Is it possible? Do I have to use other method to get the result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what for do you want to know? share gating (incentivizing) is not allowed anyway. you should always use sharing with "fire and forget".

Comment: @luschn So there isn't a way to find out if my content is actually been shared? It isn't about incentivizing because users won't 'profit' from it. But I would like to know who is doing it and the success rate of it, and this success callback would give me better data to analyze.

Comment: afaik it is only possible by authorizing with the publish_actions permission, and you will not get that one approved just for that. i believe insights show shares too, btw.

Comment: Maybe this will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655414/fbsdksharedialog-callback-for-ios

Comment: @Bannings yes, this link helped me, thanks!